# Rails - will_paginate and ActionCable server broadcast are conflicting and causing an error (undefined method `total_pages')

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using ActionCable server broadcast when updating an item. After adding will_paginate, it now causes an error. When I remove the broadcast from the update method, it works fine. When it's included, I get the following error when trying to update:

> **NoMethodError in Products#update**
>
> undefined method `total_pages' for #< Product::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007fb750e24eb0>
>
> Showing /Users/matt/rails/store/app/views/store/index.html.erb where line #33 raised:

```
<div class="flickr_pagination">
  <%= will_paginate @products %>
</div>
```

product_controller.rb

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  ...

  def index
    @search = Product.search(params[:q])
    @products = @search.result
    @products = @products.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 25)
  end
  
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update(product_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @product }
        @products = Product.all
        ActionCable.server.broadcast 'products', html: render_to_string('store/index', layout: false)
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  
  ...
end
```

This is the line that's causing the problem... Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast 'products', html: render_to_string('store/index', layout: false)
```

Comment: Please update the question with `stores_controller#index` action

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `paginate` before calling `will_paginate`:

```
@products = Product.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 25)
ActionCable.server.broadcast 'products', html: render_to_string('store/index', layout: false)
```

Comment: @mxvx, as a corollary to this, it might be beneficial for you to just broadcast the changed product and have your subscribers update only if that product is currently visible.  That way, you sidestep the pagination issue entirely and broadcast less information.